# How can I extract and calculate the price for an array of objects which have the properties price

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, nsarray

I have an array of objects and each object have the property Price.
What I want is to extract the price for each object and after to make the sum of that prices and at the end to show the TotalPrice in a label.
For the moment my array of prices is going crazy and I don't know why.

This is my code for the moment:

```
 class CartViewController: UIViewController {
        var productsInCartArray = [Product]()
        var productPricesArray = [Float]()

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            let cell = cartTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: Constants.identifierCartTotalPriceCell, for: indexPath) as! CartTableViewCell

            var totalSum: Float = 0

            for eachProduct in productsInCartArray{
                productPricesArray.append(eachProduct.price)
                totalSum = productPricesArray.reduce(0, +)

                cell.cartTotalPriceLabel.text = String(totalSum)

                return cell
            }
        }
 }
```

And here is a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Can you post valid code please. You have mismatched curly braces. And please indent your code so it's readable.

Comment: Ok I added the curly braces and the line for `let cell`, Thanks !

Comment: What happens when you click on add to cart button? Can you add the code for that? Also how and when are you adding products to `productsInCart` array?

Comment: This is still missing a closing curly brace. If you want effective help format the code correctly... help us help you.

Comment: @hardikparmar the add function is working. Is adding the correct item from first view to second view. I just need help with my Price Calculation. If you want to know how I append from FirstView to SecondView then here is the code: `let products = ((self.tabBarController?.viewControllers![0] as! UINavigationController).topViewController as! ProductsViewController).selectedProductsArray`

Answer (score 0):

productPricesArray is an instance variable, not a local variable, so you're adding an element to productPricesArray each time you generate a cell; if you have two cells, you'll have 4 prices in that array. In addition, each time you reloadData() on this table, it's adding more prices to that array.

You should pull that logic out of this method and instead have it fire before calling reloadData on the table (or some other load time).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the `productPricesArray.append(eachProduct.price)` part in `cellForRow`.
Well, `cellForRow` will be called multiple times. You should not put such logics in `cellForRow`, it is a bad idea.

What you should do is, calculate the price before you call `reloadData`. For example, where you are adding the product in `productsInCart` array, you should also add the product price in `productPrices` array. So in `cellForRow`, you will only be summing up the array which is fine.

Answer (score 0):

you just need to do this to calculate the total for all the cells:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = cartTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: Constants.identifierCartTotalPriceCell, for: indexPath) as! CartTableViewCell

    let calculate = String(productsInCartArray.map{$0.price}.reduce(0.0, +))
    cell.cartTotalPriceLabel.text = "$\(calculate)"
    return cell
}
```

it just can't calculate the total with the quantity, im sorry that I couldn't be of further help

Comment: SideNote: I'm stuck on a similar issue where im trying to calculate the total but instead im trying to calculate the total for the sections in tableview